# How do I call Awk Print Variable within Expect Script that uses Spawn?

Tags: bash, escaping, tcl, expect, quoting

I've been creating some basic system health checks, and one of the checks includes a yum repo health status that uses one of Chef's tools called 'knife'. However, when I try to awk a column, I get

```
can't read "4": no such variable.
```

Here is what I am currently using:

```
read -s -p "enter password: " pass
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn knife ssh -m host1 "sudo bash -c \"yum repolist -v| grep Repo-name| awk '{print $4}'\" "
expect {
-nocase password: { send "$pass\r" }; expect eof }
}
EOF
```

I've tried other variations as well, such as replacing the awk single quotes with double curly braces, escaping the variable, and even setting the variable to the command, and keep getting the same negative results:

```
awk {{print $4}}
awk '{print \$4}'
awk '\{print \$4\}'
awk {\{print \$4\}}
```

Does anyone know how I can pass this awk column selector variable within a spawned knife ssh command that sends the variable to the ssh host?

Comment: Replace `$4` with `\\\$4`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Any idea why it required 3 backslashes? I'm assuming one is escaping the backslash, but not sure what the third one is doing?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 "sudo bash -c \"yum repolist -v|grep Repo-name|awk '{print $4}'\""
```

has many layers of quoting (Tcl/Expect, ssh, bash, awk), and it's quoting of different types. Such things are usually pretty nasty and can require using rather a lot of backslashes to persuade values to go through the outer layers unmolested.  In particular, Tcl and the shell both want to get their hands on variables whose uses start with `$` and continue with alpha**numerics**. (Backslashes that go in deep need to be themselves quoted with more backslashes, making the code hard to read and hard to understand precisely.)

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 "sudo bash -c \"yum repolist -v|grep Repo-name|awk '{print \\\$4}'\""
```

However, there's one *big* advantage available to us: we can put much of the code into braces at the outer level as we are not actually substituting anything from Tcl in there.

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 {sudo bash -c "yum repolist -v|grep Repo-name|awk '{print \$4}'"}
```

The thing inside the braces is conventional shell code, not Tcl. And in fact we can probably simplify further, as neither `grep` nor `awk` need to be elevated:

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 {sudo bash -c "yum repolist -v"|grep Repo-name|awk '{print $4}'}
```

Depending on the `sudo` configuration, you might even be able to do this (which I'd actually rather people did on systems I controlled anyway, rather than giving general access to root shells out):

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 {sudo yum repolist -v|grep Repo-name|awk '{print $4}'}
```

And if my `awk` is good enough, you can get rid of the `grep` like this:

```
spawn knife ssh -m host1 {sudo yum repolist -v|awk '/Repo-name/{print $4}'}
```

This is starting to look more manageable. However, if you want to substitute `Repo-name` for a Tcl variable, you need a little more work that reintroduces a backslash, but now it is all much tamer than before as there's fewer layers of complexity to create headaches.

```
set repo "Repo-name"
spawn knife ssh -m host1 "sudo yum repolist -v|awk '/$repo/{print \$4}'"
```

In practice, I'd be more likely to get rid of the `awk` entirely and do that part in Tcl code, as well as setting up *key-based* direct access to the root account, allowing avoiding the `sudo`, but that's getting rather beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Good analysis and advice. Note that if you're using an _unquoted_ here-doc, as the OP does, you still need `\$4`, even with `{...}`, to prevent the _shell_ from prematurely expanding `$4`.

Comment: _Another_ layer of quoting?! As if all the levels that there were weren't enough! It's a good idea in programming to try to avoid writing lots of quoting; it's not that you can't get it right, it's that it is annoying to get it right. Splitting the code up into several files with simple quoting schemes is far more maintainable...

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for taking the time to write this, this clearly describes what's taken place, as well as how to improve the current logic. I am completely in favor of ssh key-based direct access, but unfortunately it will not be available within this particular environment.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Absolutely agreed that layering quoting is to be avoided (which is why I recommend passing shell variable values as _arguments_ in my answer). My point is that the _question_ is predicated on an _unquoted_ here-doc, in which shell expansions invariably happen - an unquoted here-doc was presumably chosen, because `$pass` is embedded in the `expect` script by shell expansion - yet your answer shows (some) commands that assume that this extra layer isn't there, without saying so.

Answer (score 1):

[Donal Fellows' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41777747/45375) contains great analysis and advice.

To complement it with an explanation of **why replacing `$4` with `\\\$4` worked**:

The goal is ultimately for `awk` to see `$4` as-is, so we must escape for all intermediate layers in which `$` has special meaning.

I'll use a simplified command in the examples below.

Let's start by temporarily eliminating the *shell* layer, by *quoting* the opening here-doc delimiter as `'EOF'`, which makes the content behave like a single-quoted string; i.e., the shell treats the content as a *literal*, without applying expansions:

```
expect <<'EOF'  # EOF is quoted -> literal here-doc
spawn bash -c "awk '{ print \$1 }' <<<'hi there'"
expect eof
EOF
```

Output:

```
spawn bash -c awk '{ print $1 }' <<<'hi there'
hi
```

Note that `$1` had to be escaped as `\$1` to prevent *`expect`* from interpreting it as an `expect` variable reference.

Given that the here-doc in your question uses an *unquoted* opening here-doc delimiter (`EOF`), the shell treats the content as if it were a *double-quoted string*; i.e, shell expansions *are* applied.

Given that the shell now expands the script first, we must add an extra layer of escaping *for the shell*, by prepending *two* extra `\` to `\$1`:

```
expect <<EOF  # EOF is unquoted -> shell expansions happen
spawn bash -c "awk '{ print \\\$1 }' <<<'hi there'"
expect eof
EOF
```

This yields the same output as above.

Based on the rules of parsing an unquoted here-doc (which, as stated, is parsed like a double-quoted string), the shell turns `\\` into a single `\`, and `\$1` into literal `$1`, combining to literal `\$1`, which is what the `expect` script needs to see.
(Verify with `echo "\\\$1"` in the shell.)

---

#### Simplifying the approach with command-line arguments and a *quoted* here-doc:

As you can see, the multiple layers of quoting (escaping) can get confusing.

One way to avoid problems is to:

- use a *quoted* here-doc, so that the shell doesn't interpret it in any way, so you can then focus on `expect`'s quoting needs
- pass any *shell* variable values via *command-line arguments*, and reference them from inside the `expect` script as *expressions* (either directly or by assigning them to an `expect` variable first).

```
expect -f - 'hi there' <<'EOF'
set txt [lindex $argv 0]
spawn bash -c "awk '{ print \$1 }' <<<'$txt'"
expect eof
EOF
```

Text `hi there` is passed as the 1st (and only) command-line argument, which can be referenced as `[lindex $argv 0]` in the script.
(`-f -` simply explicitly tells `expect` to read its script from stdin, which is necessary here to distinguish the script from the arguments).

`set txt ...` creates `expect` variable `$txt`, which can then be used unquoted or as part of double-quoted strings.

To create *literal* strings in `expect`, use `{...}` (the equivalent of the shell's `'...'`).

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated! I don't normally mix tcl with bash, so it's nice to read through your run down.

Comment: @hobbes: My pleasure. As your use case demonstrates, when you do need to mix them, it's better to keep those worlds apart, and have them communicate via command-line arguments.